# Syntax Error "syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' " While checking existence of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails application I need to check if an object exists and if it does, I need to assign the latitude and longitude attributes of that  object to two external variables named latitude and longitude.

```
my controller code 
      def query

      if ( Coordinates.where(city :params[:show]).exists?) equal? 1) then

                           a=Coordinates.where(city: params[:show])

                              latitude=a.latitude

                             longitude=a.longitude

                        end
```

But When I run the  program  In the browser I am getting syntax error despite I tried several times changing the syntax The error I am getting is "syntax error, unexpected tFID, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'". Anybody please help me how to solve this problem ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've got several remarks:

- in Ruby the syntax for an if is generally (without then)

  ```
  if condition
    code
  end
  ```
- where returns a ActiveRecord Association, thus it is a collection so you can't call `a.latitude` for example. Try `Coordinates.where(city: params[:show]).first` or something like that.
- have you defined a method called `equal?`? If not there is at least a `.` missing.
- The if statement is more or less useless.

  ```
   def query
     a = Coordinates.where(city: params[:show])
     b = a.first
     if a.count == 1
       latitude = b.latitude
       longitude= b.longitude
     else
       # do something else
     end
   end
  ```

Comment: it says "can't convert smbol to integer" . Can you please help me?

Comment: can you tell me where exactly that happens?

Comment: The line where I have typed a=Coordinates.where(city: params[:show])

Comment: Then I guess you're using Ruby version 1.8.7 or something < 1.9.
The syntax before 1.9 for hashs was `:key => value` instead of `key: value`.
You could try changing that line to `a = Coordinates.where(:city => params[:show])` and see if that fixes that problem.

Comment: I am using version 1.9.2 only .Is it possible to convert to integer first using  to_i and then assign?

Comment: That would not solve the problem. It appears that rails has an array where you think you have a hash. So it is probably params, that should be a hash, but you have got an array. Because arrays only take integers to access it tries to convert `:show` to an integer to have an index.
I can't help you any further without seeing more of the code.

Answer (score 1):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
( Coordinates.where(city :params[:show]).exists?) equal? 1)
```

What exactly do you want to know? In this case it might be better to explain it to us in words, because your code seems confusing. Ayonix has a working example of the query method, but I'm not sure if that method describes exactly what you want to know.

Comment: it is something like  I want to check if the user enters , I want to check if that exists in the table and if it exists I want to assign the latitude and longitude attributes of the table  to the external variables latitude and longitude. Latitude and longitude are two attributes of the table